# Get the image title and alt from custom query

Tags: php, theme-development, images

I think this will be a simple question for anyone who is familiar with WordPress and PHP. I'm not a PHP guru, so that's why I ask you guys! What we want is simple. Our images have a title and alt desc. But we want to echo them in the theme.

Below is the code where it should be echoed. Yes, I was able to find the piece of code responsible for this ;-). Any suggestions?
[image]

```
        while( have_posts() ) :

        the_post();

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( (int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , "_thumbnail_id" , true ) , "collection" );
        $large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( (int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , "_thumbnail_id" , true ) , "original" );

        $terms_array = array();

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID() , "brand" );

        $brand_image = "";

        $has_brand_names = array();

        foreach( $terms as $term ) :

            if( !$brand_image ) $brand_image = $brand_images["brand-".$term->term_id];

            $terms_array[] = "brand-" . $term->term_id;

            $has_brand_names[ $term->slug ] = true;

        endforeach;

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID() , "collection_subcategory" );

        foreach( $terms as $term ) :

            $terms_array[] = "subcategory-" . $term->term_id;

        endforeach;

        printf( "<div class='shoe %s' data-image='%s' data-large-image='%s' ><div class='shoe-outer' ><div class='shoe-inner' ><img src='%s' ></div></div></div>", join(" ", $terms_array ), esc_attr( $image[0] ), esc_attr( $large_image[0] ), $brand_image );

    endwhile;
```

Comment: You want to display the image with custom title and alt text... right?
Are you getting any errors in the above code?

Comment: Hi Sid, the image has a title, this we want to echo on the printf as well. Currenty we don't have any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code, just after `$large_image`, you can add this :

```
$image_alt = get_post_meta((int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , "_thumbnail_id" , true ), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$image_title = get_the_title((int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , "_thumbnail_id" , true ));
```

The `alt` for attachment is stock in `post_meta` (`_wp_attachment_image_alt`), the title is a `post_title`.

And then your replace the value in your `printf()`.

**EDIT:**

```
printf( "<div class='shoe %s' data-image='%s' data-large-image='%s' ><div class='shoe-outer' ><div class='shoe-inner' ><img src='%s' alt='%s' title='%s' ></div></div></div>", join(" ", $terms_array ), esc_attr( $image[0] ), esc_attr( $large_image[0] ), $brand_image, $image_alt, $image_title );
```

Tell me if it's work :)

Comment: I'm not really a hero with printf. Could you show me how to modify? I've added them to the printf, but now we have a error.

Comment: Answer is update :)

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing to see unfortunatly :-(. It is the featured image of a post. I've added an image to show you.

Comment: Can you try to dump the 2 variables ? `$image_alt`, `$image_title`

Comment: I've dumped them. With $image_title I see the image name because that's the name from the image. But I want the featured post image title. Is this a different field?

Comment: You have paste the code I give you just after `$large_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( (int)get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , "_thumbnail_id" , true ) , "original" );` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70550/discussion-between-wouter-and-jean-remi-larcelet-prost).